# Stateful transducers in core.async

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

Im trying to understand how to make stateful transducers in core.async.
For example how would I make a transducer that counts the number of elements that have come throgh a channel? For example I want to input to be transfomed into a count that depends on the number of objects that have come before it.

From what I have read the way to go is to use `volatile!` to hold the state inside the transducer but im still not sure how to put all things together.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by counting number of elements? you mean that you put some objects into a channel and then what? Like when you take some val from that channel, it should return number of elements written to it? Or something like `keep-indexed` transducer does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a stateful transducer returning a reducing function closed over a [`volatile!`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/volatile!) tracking the count.

```
(defn count-xf [rf]
  (let [ctr (volatile! 0)]
    (fn
      ([] (rf))
      ([result] (rf result))
      ([result _]                         ; we ignore the input as
       (rf result (vswap! ctr inc))))))   ; we just pass on the count
```

This can be simplified using the core function [`completing`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/completing)

```
(defn count-xf [rf]
  (let [ctr (volatile! 0)]
    (completing
     (fn [result _]
       (rf result (vswap! ctr inc))))))
```

E. g. use it so

```
(let [ch (chan 1 count-xf)]
  (onto-chan ch (repeat 10 true))
  (<!! (clojure.core.async/into [] ch)))

;-> [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]
```

Alternatively, you could just use the [`map-indexed`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/map-indexed) transducer but this would likely help you less to understand how transducers work. Also it requires a bit additional per-step overhead for this particular usecase.

```
(def count-xf (map-indexed (fn [i _] (inc i))))
```

Observe that its [implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6997) diverges little from the implementation above.

Further reference: http://clojure.org/reference/transducers